# Symfony 3 authentication provider fallback

Tags: authentication, symfony, facebook-authentication

I have implemented authentication mechanism on some mobile application using [JWTBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) with symfony 3. Until now the process requires users to submit both their email and  password in order to authenticate. This works great.

Today I would like to grant access/create_account using Facebook authentication.

From the mobile app, users will access the application without submitting any password but instead FB will probably return user's Facebook identifier along with some other info. I will then post those datas to *login_check* route.

At this point **I need a way to check (at the very beginning of request processing flow) whether login_check POST datas are standard username/pwd credentials (which I guess are handled through daoauthenticationprovider by default ? which in turn pass the processing to JWT in order to create a authentication token) and if not, fallback to another custom XXAuthenticationProvider to handle those datas (eg. if a facebook identifier is present then lookup the user account with FB API, do stuff … then create a JWT token).**

I read couples of articles dealing with Symfony's Security components but none explained the whole thing clearly neither exposed a way to proceed. I still have difficulties to figure out how I could hook into the security firewall to achieve this.

Is this a way to go and how can I achieve this ?
Thank you.

Comment: You can take a look on [guard authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html) for handle multiple auth, (added on sf2.8)

Comment: @Glasset Thank you for suggesting but we would like to comply to the existing codebase and use "raw" listeners instead. We may use Guard as we will be upgrading Symfony Framework to latest version.